# Randomizing http request path in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Currently my jmeter tests have a few GET http requests. In the request, i've got data filled in the "path" field.

I'm looking for a way to randomize Jmeter so it will call an array of "paths", however i can't seem to figure this out. Anyone have any tips?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JMeter's test element most commonly used for parametrization and data-driven testing is [CSV  Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)
2. There are built-in JMeter Functions which can be used to get data from external sources

   - [__StringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)
   - [__CSVRead](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)
3. There is a [chooseRandom](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) function available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)